# Nested for loops and functions

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I originally wrote a sequence of `for` loops to change the value in the "Reporte" variable of a data frame called "x_1".

```
   for (i in seq(x_1$Reporter)){
     if (x_1$Reporter[i]=="52") {x_1$ReporterN[i]<-"Barbados"}
   }
...
   for (i in seq(x_1$Reporter)){
     if (x_1$Reporter[i]=="70") {x_1$ReporterN[i]<-"Bosnia Herzegovina"}
   }
...
```

I'd like to make it work over a list of data frames (say, sx_148, sx_101, where the numbers have no ordering meaning) instead of only "x_1".

I tried many ways but I could not.

Comment: Well show us what you tried and where it went wrong...It's easier to diagnose a problem that way

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of your data frames (`dfList` in my example), and then use `lapply()` to apply a function to each data frame.

```
dfList <- list(
  sx_148,
  sx_101
)

dfList <- lapply(dfList, function(x) {
  x$ReporterN[x$Reporter == "52"] <- "Barbados"
  x$ReporterN[x$Reporter == "70"] <- "Bosnia Herzegovina"
  return(x)
})
```

If you want to act on more data frames, just add them to the list.